# Issues with replacing ' " ' in a string

Tags: java, string, replace

I'm trying to remove a substring from a string that contains the text `"matchup"` in quotes. The complete substring to be removed reads something like `To get an in-depth statistical preview, click "matchup" at the top of the screen`.

I'm trying to do a

```
string.replace("To get an in-depth statistical preview, click "matchup" at the top of the screen", "");
```

which would replace that long sentence with a blank; however since "matchup" actually has quotation marks around it in the string, when I pass that in as an argument it freaks out and thinks I have two separate strings with some random piece of text `matchup` in between them.

Sorry if this is difficult to understand, I may be doing a bad job of it. I have also tried doing

```
...'matchup'.... rather than ..."matchup"...
```

and it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Escape the " like this \"

Comment: If this is Java code, your example will not even compile. Are you sure the `java` tag is appropriate here?

Answer (score 7):

you can use `\"` to represent `"` in a string

therefore

```
string.replace("To get an in-depth statistical preview, click \"matchup\" at the top of the screen", "")
```

Answer (score 1):

Add some delimiters, IE `string.replace(" my \"string\" ", " ")`

Answer (score 1):

Some characters need to be *escaped* in string literals (or even character literals) as explained [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html) for Java.

You should use `\"` to represent `"`

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to remove a string that contains the following text
>
> "matchup"

```
string.replace("\"matchup\"", "")
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the quotes with `\"`, as

```
String newString = string.replace("To get an in-depth statistical preview, click \"matchup\" at the top of the screen", "");
```

Because strings are immutable, `replace` doesn't work in-place and you need to assign the result of `string.replace(..., ...)` to a new string.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is that use the `\"` to show `"`.